# iOS Interface Builder: Login into two separate user types

Tags: ios

I am wanting to utilize Xcode 5's interface builder using storyboards.

Being that Xcode has been moving faster than most of the online tutorials, I have struggled to find anything remotely close to details on utilizing storyboards with Logins prior to the users profile interface. Here's a briefing on what I am working on and what I have done (with no luck)

- It starts out with UINavigationViewController that acts as a "login" initial view controller. Once this initial viewController's requirements are filled, the users' input will determine which one, of the 2, interfaces they will be accessing.
- Each interface (1 & 2) will be a UITabBarViewController with separate functionality (only by the user types). With this being said, the user interaction and use of one interface will be required to populate the the other user type's views.

  1. Should I separate the login and interfaces into individual storyboards and then reconnect them programmatically with an empty ViewController that acts as a translator and connector to the type? I came up with this theory here: http://robsprogramknowledge.blogspot.com/search/label/UIStoryboard
  2. Would setting up one large storyboard that holds all the views be the best bet?
  3. Has anyone come across anything that helps explain how to implement these type of new interface builder "solutions"?

I have managed to separate the login storyboard from the user type interfaces, but was only successful with accessing and "logging into" one of the user types, not both, when using the recommendations from the storyboard tutorial link above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to build your `storeyboard` module wise. and use followings [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8297701/using-multiple-storyboards-in-ios) and [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21066508/best-way-to-use-multiple-storyboards-in-app) to merge them. It will be easy for you if multiple people are working on same project for merging purpose. Else there is a mess if multiple people working on same project with single storeyboard .

Regarding different views for multiple type user you can specify identifier to invoke view progrmatically or use `seague` to different view